# sign extension in C, char>unsigned char

Tags: c, casting, char, bit

When i was reading K&R, i am confused in this code:

```
#include "syscalls.h"
int getchar(void)
{
    char c;

    return (read(0, &c, 1) == 1) ? (unsigned char)c : EOF;
}
```

It is said  unsigned char used for avoiding the wrong brought by sign extension in this code.
This is the only case i can think of,and i give this example code:

```
char c = 0xf0; //11110000, just make highest bit > 1
printf("%i\n",(int)(unsigned char)c);
printf("%i\n",(int)c);

Output:  240 // 0...011110000
         -16 // 1...111110000
```

But in fact ascii is just 0~127
highest bit can not be assigned to 1.Why in K&R cast char >> unsigned char?

Comment: What makes you think that a `char` needs to be limited to the ASCII character set ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASCII *is* limited to the range `0..127` but it's not only ASCII that can be read by `read` - in K&R, it could get the entire `0..255` range of `char` values.

That's why `getchar` returned an `int`, because it had to be able to return *any* `char` value plus a special `EOF` value that was distinct from *all* other characters.

By casting the character to an `unsigned char` before promoting it to an `int` on return, it prevented the values `128..255` being sign-extended. If you allowed that sign extension, you would not have been able to tell the difference between 255 (which would sign extend to all 1-bits) and `EOF` (which was -1, all 1-bits).

---

I'm not *entirely* certain your strategy of using K&R to learn the language is a good one by the way. C has come a *long* way since those days. From memory, even the latest K&R book was still for the C89/90 ANSI standard (before ISO basically took over responsibility) and the language has been through *two* massive upgrades since then.

Comment: Thanks,but can you teach me how to print and get a wrong output with using a no cast getchar() :) My PC:Ubuntu13 x64

Comment: I use this book in the case i know the different between C99 C90.K&R is not for First learning

Comment: @pup007, just create a file containing a single byte `0xff` followed by a printable string. You'll find the cast from char 255 to int will give you -1 (eof) and it will never read the other chars, assuming of course chars are signed, chars are 8 bits and a host of other things that may have changed in the last 20 years.

Comment: Thanks,i understand it, getchar() read char from standard input,but can redierct to a file.  (Everything may change.) :)

Answer (score 1):

unsigned char variables have values between 0 and 255 and for the requirement of typecasting please follow comment from the same book

```
Whether plain chars are signed or unsigned is machine-dependent, but printable characters are always positive.
```

Now if we talk about c standard then it is given as below

```
The implementation shall define char to have the same range, representation, and behavior as either signed char or unsigned char.
```

Comment: Another example of an anchronism. Most locales have printable characters in the 128-255 range.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck i was trying to show the comment in that book given in favour of such typecasting.

Comment: My comment wasn't meant to be a critique on your answer, merely an observation supporting paxdiablo's claim that K&R's book is a poor choice for learning newer versions of C.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck for example?

Comment: @pupu007 Anything but plain 7-bit ascii. For example: ISO8859-1 and CP1252.

Answer (score 1):

```
return (read(0, &c, 1) == 1) ? (unsigned char)c : EOF;
```

means: read one char into c; iif you could read at least one char, return it; otherwise return (the int) EOF.

note that getchar() returns an int, thus the conversion is char->unsigned char->int